# XSL Transformation - Master detail

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform XML from one structure to another. I am not sure how to do this. The first xml doesnt really look like master detail but the resulting one need to look like mast detail.

```
   <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
    <Root-Element xmlns="http://example.com/ReadProductB">
       <RECORD1>
          <C2>QGGG9.A1-1</C2>
       </RECORD1>
       <RECORD2>
          <C2>xflowcode</C2>
          <C3>FL1</C3>
       </RECORD2>
       <RECORD2>
          <C2>xtilo</C2>
          <C3>1234</C3>
       </RECORD2>
       <RECORD2>
          <C2>xwat</C2>
          <C3>75</C3>
       </RECORD2>
       <RECORD1>
          <C2>QGGG9.A1-2</C2>
       </RECORD1>
       <RECORD2>
          <C2>xflowcode</C2>
          <C3>FL1</C3>
       </RECORD2>
       <RECORD2>
          <C2>xtilo</C2>
          <C3>1234</C3>
       </RECORD2>
       <RECORD2>
          <C2>xwat</C2>
          <C3>75</C3>
       </RECORD2>
    </Root-Element>
```

This is the result I want.

```
   <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
    <ns0:ProductCollection xmlns:ns0="http://example.com/ReadProductBB" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <ns0:RECORD1>
          <ns0:C2>QGGG9.A1-1</ns0:C2>
          <ns0:RECORD2Collection>
             <ns0:RECORD2>
                <ns0:C2>xflowcode</ns0:C2>
                <ns0:C3>FL1</ns0:C3>
             </ns0:RECORD2>
             <ns0:RECORD2>
                <ns0:C2>xtilo</ns0:C2>
                <ns0:C3>1234</ns0:C3>
             </ns0:RECORD2>
             <ns0:RECORD2>
                <ns0:C2>xwat</ns0:C2>
                <ns0:C3>75</ns0:C3>
             </ns0:RECORD2>
          </ns0:RECORD2Collection>
       </ns0:RECORD1>
       <ns0:RECORD1>
          <ns0:C2>QGGG9.A1-2</ns0:C2>
          <ns0:RECORD2Collection>
             <ns0:RECORD2>
                <ns0:C2>xflowcode</ns0:C2>
                <ns0:C3>FL1</ns0:C3>
             </ns0:RECORD2>
             <ns0:RECORD2>
                <ns0:C2>xtilo</ns0:C2>
                <ns0:C3>1234</ns0:C3>
             </ns0:RECORD2>
             <ns0:RECORD2>
                <ns0:C2>xwat</ns0:C2>
                <ns0:C3>75</ns0:C3>
             </ns0:RECORD2>
          </ns0:RECORD2Collection>
       </ns0:RECORD1>
    </ns0:ProductCollection>
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:b="http://example.com/ReadProductB"
    xmlns:bb="http://example.com/ReadProductBB"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!--
        identity template
        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform
    -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--
        converts elements from the namespace "http://example.com/ReadProductB"
        to "http://example.com/ReadProductBB" 
    -->
    <xsl:template match="b:*">
        <xsl:element name="bb:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b:Root-Element">  
        <!--Convert b:Root-Element into bb:ProductCollection-->
        <bb:ProductCollection>
            <!--and then "push" only the b:RECORD1 elements -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="b:RECORD1"/>
        </bb:ProductCollection>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b:RECORD1">
        <!--Convert the RECORD1 to new namespace -->
        <bb:RECORD1>
            <!-- "push" it's children 
            (which will match the generic templates above)-->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <bb:RECORD2Collection>
              <!--and "push" the RECORD2 elements that are 
                between this RECORD1 element and the next(or the end) -->
              <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::b:RECORD2
                      [generate-id(preceding-sibling::b:RECORD1[1])
                       = generate-id(current())]" />
            </bb:RECORD2Collection>
        </bb:RECORD1>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Apologies. I was a bit vague with my question. I am new to all this stuff so didn't realize how to properly form my question. I will try to bit harder next time.

Comment: I was struggling for more than few days with this problem and you guys came up with solution / suggestion with in no time. Kudos to you. Really appreciate your help. I actually have the xsd for the resulting xml that I want. I will give it a try with your suggestion tomorrow and get back. A little late at night right now.

Comment: I realized that I had neglected to include `<bb:RECORD2Collection>` in the output, made an update to my answer.

Comment: As for learning XSLT and XPath, Dave Pawson's site is a good reference - has compiled lots of FAQ, examples, and helpful hints http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/index.html. Jeni Tennison has a good set of tutorials http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/.

Comment: Thanks a lot, if worked as expected. Great work. Also thanks to the pointers for the reference sites. I will have a look. For now first I need to understand how your xsl is working :)

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet uses a general-purpose template to move the original elements to those of the same name in namespace `ns0`.

The `RECORD2` elements are paired with their corresponding `RECORD1` element by using `generate-id` to identify the current `RECORD1`, and then processing all following `RECORD2` elements whose first preceding `RECORD1` element has the same id.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:src="http://example.com/ReadProductB"
    xmlns:ns0="http://example.com/ReadProductBB"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="src"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/src:Root-Element">
        <ns0:ProductCollection>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="src:RECORD1"/>
        </ns0:ProductCollection>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="src:RECORD1">
        <ns0:RECORD1>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:variable name="record1" select="generate-id()"/>
            <ns0:RECORD2Collection>
                <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::src:RECORD2">
                    <xsl:if test="generate-id(preceding-sibling::src:RECORD1[1]) = $record1">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ns0:RECORD2Collection>
        </ns0:RECORD1>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="ns0:{local-name(current())}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:ProductCollection xmlns:ns0="http://example.com/ReadProductBB" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <ns0:RECORD1>
      <ns0:C2>QGGG9.A1-1</ns0:C2>
      <ns0:RECORD2Collection>
         <ns0:RECORD2>
            <ns0:C2>xflowcode</ns0:C2>
            <ns0:C3>FL1</ns0:C3>
         </ns0:RECORD2>
         <ns0:RECORD2>
            <ns0:C2>xtilo</ns0:C2>
            <ns0:C3>1234</ns0:C3>
         </ns0:RECORD2>
         <ns0:RECORD2>
            <ns0:C2>xwat</ns0:C2>
            <ns0:C3>75</ns0:C3>
         </ns0:RECORD2>
      </ns0:RECORD2Collection>
   </ns0:RECORD1>
   <ns0:RECORD1>
      <ns0:C2>QGGG9.A1-2</ns0:C2>
      <ns0:RECORD2Collection>
         <ns0:RECORD2>
            <ns0:C2>xflowcode</ns0:C2>
            <ns0:C3>FL1</ns0:C3>
         </ns0:RECORD2>
         <ns0:RECORD2>
            <ns0:C2>xtilo</ns0:C2>
            <ns0:C3>1234</ns0:C3>
         </ns0:RECORD2>
         <ns0:RECORD2>
            <ns0:C2>xwat</ns0:C2>
            <ns0:C3>75</ns0:C3>
         </ns0:RECORD2>
      </ns0:RECORD2Collection>
   </ns0:RECORD1>
</ns0:ProductCollection>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate a lot. Your response time is mind boggling. I will give it a try to your solution and get back to you soon. I have the xsd for the resulting xml which I should have posted. I am only new to all these so apologies.

Comment: Since you guys are so good, can you please give me a suggestion, whats the best way to learn all this stuff. I know experience matters a lot but how to make a good start. Are there any online courses available? Thanks again.

Comment: XSLT is on of the most poorly documented languages I have come across. [The specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) is fairly impenetrable, and most tutorials are superficial, and the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) one is one of the best. I wonder why you've removed your acceptance of my answer. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Your answer works perfect and gives the exact result what I was looking for. I am bit confused about the selection of answer. Both the answers are right but I can only select one of them, if I click on yours the other goes away. I am not sure how to do this. Your answer is 100% correct.

Comment: @user2351802: I'm afraid you can accept only one. Choose the one that is best in any way you can think of :)

Comment: Also thanks for the pointers to the sites. I am trying to understand what your code is doing. Will it be possible for you to provide some explanation how its working. Hopefully I would be able to pick up something that I can use in the future rather than just copy paste :)

Comment: @user2351802: That would be fine. We will be invited to take this to a private chat shortly.